# Build Error using IL2CPP: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform."

Tags: unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I've run into some trouble when changing the Scripting Backend from Mono to IL2CPP to support Android x64 since Google says it's necessary.

I've tried to search all over the internet for a fix, but couldn't find anything.

The error: 
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Comment: Have you solved it?